# Is there a format processor to write my own printf-like function and keep the %d style arguments, without using sprintf?

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, printf, uart

I'm writing a serial interface for an MCU, and I want to know how one would create a `printf`-like function to write to the serial UART.  I can write to the UART, but to save memory and stack space, and avoid temp string buffers, I would prefer to do that write directly instead of doing `sprintf()` to a string and then writing the string via serial.  There is no kernel and no file handling, so `FILE*` writes like those from `fprintf()` won't work (but `sprintf()` does).

Is there something that processes formatted strings for each char, so I can print char-by-char as it parses the format string, and applies the related arguments?

We are using [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) as part of the [efm32-base project](https://github.com/ryankurte/efm32-base/).

## **UPDATE**

I would like to note that ultimately we implemented the _write() function because thats all newlib needs to light up printf.

Comment: When you say "write to the UART ... directly" how do you mean? What code are you hoping to use?

Comment: BTW, temporary string buffers on the stack are basically free because they can be cleaned up immediately after use and have zero creation overhead.

Comment: Do you have `fopencookie` on your system?

Comment: I don't understand well your question, but if you are using C++ I think the best way to do it is using `iostream`. Something like: `uart << my_string << " is equal to " << number;`. I use it with `atmega328` and I like it a lot. You can check an example [here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/avr/test/USART/iostream/main.cpp) and [here is the implementation](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/avr/avr_UART_iostream.h).

Comment: You might like to hack away at this: https://rsync.samba.org/doxygen/head/snprintf_8c-source.html

Comment: This is clearly embedded, and the OP is trying to keep stack sizes down.  OP - you using a tasking/thread lib/RTOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on your standard library implementation you need to write your own versions of `fputc` or `_write` functions.

Comment: I'm upping this, whoever DV'ed was wrong!  This was ultimately the correct answer for our implementation and I updated the OP to reflect that.  However, I realize this didn't directly address the question which was about re-implementing printf.  So, I'm split on where the answer should be, but this answer deserves props.  So lots of other great answers that are directly addressing the subject, but this was the fix we used.

Comment: @KJ7LNW you do not reimplement printf if you write your putc or _write as they are called by the original printf function (which one is needed you need to see in your implementation). So you will be able to use standard `printf`

Comment: Correct, we didn't re-implement printf(), we just implemented _write().

Answer (score 2):

Standard C `printf` family of functions don't have a "print to a character callback" type of functionality. Most embedded platforms don't support `fprintf` either.

First try digging around the C runtime for your platform, it might have a built-in solution. For example, ESP-IDF has `ets_install_putc1()` which essentially installs a callback for `printf` (though its `ets_printf` already prints to UART0).

Failing that, there are alternative `printf` implementations designed specifically for embedded applications which you can adapt to your needs.

For example [mpaland/printf](https://github.com/mpaland/printf) has a function taking the character printer callback as the first argument:

```
int fctprintf(void (*out)(char character, void* arg), void* arg, const char* format, ...);
```

Also see this related question: [Minimal implementation of sprintf or printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647278/minimal-implementation-of-sprintf-or-printf).

Answer (score 1):

You had said [in your top comments] that you had GNU, so `fopencookie` for the hooks [I've used it before with success].

Attaching to `stdout` may be tricky, but doable.

Note that we have: `FILE *stdout;` (i.e. it's [just] a *pointer*). So, simply setting it to the [newly] opened stream should work.

So, I *think* you can do, *either* (1):

```
FILE *saved_stdout = stdout;
```

Or (2):

```
fclose(stdout);
```

Then, (3):

```
FILE *fc = fopencookie(...);
setlinebuf(fc);  // and whatever else ...
stdout = fc;
```

You can [probably] adjust the order to suit (e.g. doing `fclose` first, etc.)

I had looked for something analogous to `freopen` or `fdopen` to fit your situation, but I didn't find anything, so doing `stdout = ...;` may be the option.

This works fine *if* you do *not* have any code that tries to write to fd 1 directly (e.g. `write(1,"hello\n",6);`).

Even in that case, there is probably a way.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Do you know if FILE*stdout is a const? If so, I might need to do something crazy like FILE **p = &stdout and then *p = fopencookie(...)

You were right to be concerned, but *not* for quite the reason you think. Read on ...

---

**`stdout` is writable *but* ...**

Before I posted, I checked `stdio.h`, and it has:

```
extern FILE *stdout;        /* Standard output stream.  */
```

If you think about it, `stdout` *must* be writable.

Otherwise, we could never do:

```
fprintf(stdout,"hello world\n");
fflush(stdout);
```

Also, if we did a `fork`, then [in the child] if we wanted to set up `stdout` to go to a logfile, we'd need to be able to do:

```
freopen("child_logfile","w",stdout);
```

So, no worries ...

---

**Trust but *verify* ...**

Did I say "no worries"? I may have been premature ;-)

There *is* an issue.

Here is a sample test program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#if 1 || DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        fprintf(stderr,_fmt); \
        fflush(stderr); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

typedef struct {
    int ioport;
} uartio_t;

char *arg = "argument";

ssize_t
my_write(void *cookie,const char *buf,size_t len)
{
    uartio_t *uart = cookie;
    ssize_t err;

    dbgprt("my_write: ENTER ioport=%d buf=%p len=%zu\n",
        uart->ioport,buf,len);

    err = write(uart->ioport,buf,len);

    dbgprt("my_write: EXIT err=%zd\n",err);

    return err;
}

int
my_close(void *cookie)
{
    uartio_t *uart = cookie;

    dbgprt("my_close: ioport=%d\n",uart->ioport);
    int err = close(uart->ioport);
    uart->ioport = -1;

    return err;
}

int
main(void)
{

    cookie_io_functions_t cookie = {
        .write = my_write,
        .close = my_close
    };
    uartio_t uart;

    printf("hello\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    uart.ioport = open("uart",O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT,0644);
    FILE *fc = fopencookie(&uart,"w",cookie);

    FILE *saved_stdout = stdout;
    stdout = fc;

    printf("uart simple printf\n");
    fprintf(stdout,"uart fprintf\n");
    printf("uart printf with %s\n",arg);

    fclose(fc);
    stdout = saved_stdout;

    printf("world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Program output:**

After compiling, running with:

```
./uart >out 2>err
```

This should produce an expected result. *But*, we get (from `head -100 out err uart`):

```
==> out <==
hello
uart simple printf
world

==> err <==
my_write: ENTER ioport=3 buf=0xa90390 len=39
my_write: EXIT err=39
my_close: ioport=3

==> uart <==
uart fprintf
uart printf with argument
```

Whoa! What happened? The `out` file *should* just be:

```
hello
world
```

And, the `uart` file *should* have *three* lines instead of *two*:

```
uart printf
uart simple printf
uart printf with argument
```

But, the `uart simple printf` line went to `out` instead of [the intended] `uart` file.

Again, whoa!, what happened?!?!

---

**Explanation:**

The program was compiled with `gcc`. Recompiling with `clang` produces the *desired* results!

It turns out that `gcc` was trying to be *too* helpful. When compiling, it converted:

```
printf("uart simple printf\n");
```

Into:

```
puts("uart simple printf");
```

We see that if we disassemble the executable [or compile with `-S` and look at the `.s` file].

The `puts` function [apparently] *bypasses* `stdout` and uses glibc's *internal* version: `_IO_stdout`.

It appears that glibc's `puts` is a *weak alias* to `_IO_puts` and that uses `_IO_stdout`.

The `_IO_*` symbols are *not* directly accessible. They're what glibc calls "hidden" symbols--available only to `glibc.so` itself.

---

**The real fix:**

I discovered this after considerable hacking around. Those attempts/fixes are in an appendix below.

It turns out that `glibc` defines (e.g.) `stdout` as:

```
FILE *stdout = (FILE *) &_IO_2_1_stdout_;
```

Internally, `glibc` uses that *internal* name. So, if we change what `stdout` points to, it *breaks* that association.

In actual fact, only `_IO_stdout` is hidden. The versioned symbol *is* global but we have to *know* the name either from `readelf` output or by using some `__GLIBC_*` macros (i.e. a bit messy).

So, we need to modify the save/restore code to *not* change the value in `stdout` but `memcpy` to/from what `stdout` *points* to.

So, in a way, *you* were correct. It is [effectively] `const` [readonly].

So, for the above sample/test program, when we want to *set* a new `stdout`, we want:

```
FILE *fc = fopencookie(...);
FILE saved_stdout = *stdout;
*stdout = *fc;
```

When we want to restore the original:

```
*fc = *stdout;
fclose(fc);
*stdout = saved_stdout;
```

So, it really wasn't `gcc` that was the issue. The original save/restore we developed was incorrect. But, it was latent. Only when `gcc` called `puts` did the bug manifest itself.

*Personal note:* Aha! Now that I got this code working, it seems oddly familiar. I'm having a *deja vu* experience. I'm pretty sure that I've had to do the same in the past. But, it was so long ago, that I had completely forgotten about it.

---

**Workarounds / fixes that semi-worked but are more complex:**

*Note:* As mentioned, these workarounds are only to show what I tried *before* finding the simple fix above.

One workaround is to disable `gcc`'s conversion from `printf` to `puts`.

The simplest way may be to [as mentioned] compile with `clang`. But, some web pages say that `clang` does the same thing as `gcc`. It does *not* do the `puts` optimization on my version of `clang` [for `x86_64`]: 7.0.1 -- YMMV

For `gcc` ...

A simple way is to compile with `-fno-builtins`. This fixes the `printf->puts` issue but disables [desirable] optimizations for `memcpy`, etc. It's also *undocumented* [AFAICT]

Another way is to force our *own* version of `puts` that calls `fputs/fputc`. We'd put that in (e.g.) `puts.c` and build and link against it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
puts(const char *str)
{
    fputs(str,stdout);
    fputc('\n',stdout);
}
```

When we just did: `stdout = fc;` we were *deceiving* `glibc` a bit [actually, glibc was deceiving *us* a bit] and that has now come back to haunt us.

The "clean" way would be to do `freopen`. But, AFAICT, there is *no* analogous function that works on a cookie stream. There *may* be one, but I haven't found it.

So, one of the "dirty" methods may be the only way. I think using the "custom" `puts` function method above would be the best bet.

*Edit:* It was after I reread the above "deceiving" sentence that I hit on the simple solution (i.e. It made me dig deeper into `glibc` source).

Comment: Can you really refine puts() without symbol collisions?  I mean maybe static, but if that works without static then I'm curious why, and does it work with other libc functions too?

Comment: Also, FYI, we use -fno-builtins in our EFR32 builds IIRC.